# Magento not using correct DB details

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

In the process of moving a Magento shop to a new server.

Have copied clean copy of files for Magento 1.5.1, then copied the app/media/shin folders to overwrite the clean ones.

All seems ok, except I am getting PDO permission denied, despite the details in local.xml being 100% correct.

I have wiped the cache folders.

Any ideas?

---

Sorted, I must have missed something, but wiping the lot and starting over seemed to fix it.

Thanks,

Comment: Has the database server been moved, too? If so, have you double checked that the database user configured in your local.xml really does exist (and has sufficient grants) on the new mySQL server?

Answer (score 0):

What home page is returning?
Have you changes values in database?
Check this query.

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/unsecure/base_url' OR path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

Comment: I have already modified these in the database, I ended up just wiping the lot and starting over, seem to be making some progress now...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't left old information in a local.bak.xml for example ? Magento reads every xml file in /app/etc